# How to add shortcode to theme

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to add a shortcode to my theme that was generated from a plugin called shortcoder.  The shortcode that the plugin generated is `[sc name="shop-beauty-all"]` and this shortcode doesn't work as `<?php echo do_shortcode("[sc name="shop-beauty-all"]"); ?>`.  Does anyone have any solutions for how I could get this to work?

```html
[sc name="shop-beauty-all"]
```

Comment: syntax error, use this <?php echo do_shortcode('[sc name="shop-beauty-all"]'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this   `<?php echo do_shortcode("[sc name='shop-beauty-all']"); ?>`
 insted of `<?php echo do_shortcode("[sc name="shop-beauty-all"]"); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content',' [sc name="shop-beauty-all"] ');
```

instead of do_shortcode, and see if it helps.